# Retry attribute is not working as expected - NUnit Framework

Tags: frameworks, attributes, nunit

We are using C# Selenium and NUnit framework for our test automation. Sometimes some test cases will fail in dev environment during execution due environmental issues. I was trying to re-run the failed ones, by using Retry attribute. But it didn't work ( I have kept assertion failures as well)

Could you please have a look the below code

```
 [TestFixture]


    public class UITests : BaseClassProtractor
    {

        [SetUp]


        public void Setup()
        {
            //**Call chrome driver and open app url set up**//


   }
[Test]
[Retry(1)]
public  TestMethod1()

{
      //** Write test Steps
}

[TearDown]


        public void TearDown()
        {
            Drivers.TryRemove(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName, out var localDriver);
            localDriver?.Quit();


        }


}
```

Thanks,
Khaja Shaik.

Comment: There's nothing to take a look at. :-) Please add some example of your code and a description of exactly what output you are seeing.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for the support. Please find sample code as below.

Comment: Hi, I have added the sample code. Could you please check once, actually test needs to retried once it is failed, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

`[Retry(1)]` indicates that the test should only be run once! That is, it won't be retried if it fails. Use `[Retry(2)]` as a minimum.

If you continue to get failures, we need to see the exact failure message.